# How to direct add content in drupal?

Tags: 7

Trying to look an answer for this but couldn't.

Default workflow of Drupal adding content is: "Add Content" > Choose Content Type. Can I just make my website to do direct adding content without need to choose the content type in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom links that aim directly to your content type in the admin tool bar.

Take a look on this link: https://drupal.org/node/1664828

Comment: Perfect! Never think of that :D